# HttpPostedFileBase return null

Tags: javascript, forms

I cannot figure out what I did wrong but for some reason HttpPostedFileBase always return null.I keep on getting null with HttpPosterFileBase when I try uploading a file on server side: Here is my code:

```
<form method="POST" id="frmNote" action="/Client/SaveNote"  enctype="multipart/form data>
Date:  @Html.TextBox("StratDate", note.StratDate)
Note: @Html.TextArea("note note.ClientNote)
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
 <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" />
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">
$("#frmNote").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
  formData.append("file", $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
            formData += "& StratDate =" + $("#StratDate").val();
            formData += "& Note =" + $("# Note ").val();
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Client/SaveNote",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function() {
                    alert("note saved successfully.");
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert(result.message);
                }
            });
    });
</script>



[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
        public JsonResult SaveNote(ActivityData note)
        {

            try
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
if (file == null)
 {

fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/image"), fileName);
   file.SaveAs(filePath);

}
                client.SaveNote(note);
                 return Json(new { error = false });
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { error = true, message = ex.Message }); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FormData.append to add all parameters to the post body of your request.

```
formData.append("file", $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
formData.append("StratDate", $("#StratDate").val());
formData.append("Note",  $("#Note").val());
```

also since you called the FormData constructor with the form that contains all the data you want to pass, you don't need to append anything to it.

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);    
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Client/SaveNote",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function() {
                alert("note saved successfully.");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert(result.message);
            }
});
```

Comment: thanks Musa, but the problem is not notes and start date I passed it as query string and it works the problem is fill up-loader it become null on controller side

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?